# Force repaint in wxPython Canvas

Tags: python, drawing, wxpython

I've got a Canvas which manipulates objects in the mouse event handler. After modifying the objects, I want to trigger the OnPaint() event for the same Canvas to show (rerender) the changes. What is the right way to do this? It doesn't let me call OnPaint() directly. Also, is triggering an event from another event "wrong" in some sense, or likely to lead to trouble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just call self.Refresh() or maybe RefreshRect() and pass the area that needs to be repainted.

Comment: After posting, I found and tried that. It was exactly what I thought I was looking for. However, when dragging one of my own objects it is very choppy. It seems refresh() only queues a repaint event but that might not happen for a while - particularly while handling mouse movement. Good try +1.

Comment: Usually when people mention stuff being choppy on the wxPython mailing list, they recommend doing it with double-buffering.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using an off screen bitmap. It wasn't that kind of choppy though. Things were very intermittent even with that. It seemed clear to me that repaint wasn't happening very often. There was no flicker, updates were immediate but infrequent.

Comment: Turns out the flicker was due to the scrolledwindow being erased prior to blitting the image. This can be disabled by grabbing the EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND event and doing nothing in it. Therefore you have the correct answer after all.

Answer (score 1):

I tried self.refresh() as suggested by Mike Driscoll. That worked partially. I'm moving my own objects with mouse events and then repainting the image - rendering my objects. So the mouse events were updating coordinates and the repaint was updating the display. The problem is that refresh() seems to be called lazily or has lower priority than the mouse events. Refresh() thus produces a choppy display.

Since I am using a buffered display via the wxDemo for Scrolled Area, I took the following line from the Paint event:

```
dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self, self.buffer, wx.BUFFER_VIRTUAL_AREA)
```

And called my drawing function with that DC from within the mouse event handler. Upon completion dc is freed and (according to the comments in the demo) copied to the screen. It was not previously clear to me how the Paint event was handling DCs, so I was trying to call the event. Turns out you can use that DC and just render from inside the mouse events. This results in smooth dragging of my custom drawn objects.